# Does Amazon Aurora Postgres support lambda invocations?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

From what I could gather in AWS's documentation, Aurora MySQL supports invoking lambda functions as triggers:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html

No such documentation for Postgres. 
Is there a way to call a lambda from a Postgres instance?

Comment: Since December 2020 [Aurora PostgreSQL supports Lambda invocations](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/amazon-aurora-postgresql-integrates-with-aws-lambda/). Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL-Lambda.html

Comment: @Infinity you should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***PostgreSQL on RDS:***

If you are using PostgreSQL on RDS, then as of now it doesn't support invoking lambda function as triggers.

***Amazon Aurora(PostgreSQL Compatibility):***

As of now this also doesn't support invoking lambda function as triggers.

***PostgreSQL on EC2:***

But if you have setup PostgreSQL on EC2, then you use leverage `PL/Python language` to create your ***User Defined Functions*** and *AWS Python SDK* to invoke Lambda functions.

In the below links, checkout the section titled **`PostgreSQL setup`** , in which they have provided detailed steps to achieve the same.

*`AWS Blog Link:`* [Set up a SQL-to-Lambda interface](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/from-sql-to-microservices-integrating-aws-lambda-with-relational-databases/)

*`GitHub Link:`* [aws-lambda-rdbms-integration](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rdbms-integration)

Comment: The question wasn't asking about standard PostgreSQL on RDS, it was asking about Amazon Aurora (PostgreSQL compatible) on RDS.

Comment: @MarkB: the first paragraph answers that question. The rest is simply a suggestion for a workaround

Comment: No, you answered the question for plain PostgreSQL on RDS. You didn't address the question of being able to invoke Lambdas from Aurora on RDS. Aurora (MySQL compatible) can invoke Lambdas directly. The question is asking if Aurora (PostgreSQL compatible) can also invoke Lambdas directly.

Comment: @MarkB: I have edited the answer so that it is clear for all.

Comment: Does Amazon Aurora Postgres support lambda invocations now?

Comment: @Raghavendra not natively, but you could add a Postgres TRIGGER which execute a postgres function and then call a lambda function

Comment: @Madeo do you have a link/reference that shows how to create a trigger and function to call a lambda function?

Comment: @DanielHair I am really sorry, but I was wrong. Unfortunately RDS for Postgres, for some unknown reason, does not allow you to run plpython extension, which basically makes impossible to issue a request to a lambda. You could perhaps use the plperl one, but since you cannot install any additional package you will have to work at lowest level of the user space.
However I have found another solution, you can use the LISTEN NOTIFY, but you will need a process to listen at all time, this means you need to deploy an EC2 or a Fargate instance that listen 24/7 for updates on a notification channel.

Comment: @Matteo you can always use a plv8 extension and bundle all the dependencies inside (webpack does it quite nicely)

Answer (score 4):

Since December 2020 Aurora PostgreSQL supports [Lambda invocations](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/amazon-aurora-postgresql-integrates-with-aws-lambda/). Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL-Lambda.html).

Comment: I always get a timeout while trying to invoke a lambda from Postgres.

Comment: @RahulPatel probably did not set up VPC correctly. Timeout usually means - firewall.